# How to get Digest vlue generated from Cache Mediator?

Tags: wso2-esb

I am working on Cache Mediator in wso2esb. My requirement is to get Hash Digest value generated by org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator class in this mediator.

```
<sequence name="In_Seq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">

      <cache  collector="false"
        hashGenerator="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator"
        id="MyCache" maxMessageSize="2000" scope="per-host" timeout="120">
        <onCacheHit/>
        <implementation maxSize="1000" type="memory"/>
      </cache></sequence>
<sequence name="Out_Seq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
 <cache collector="true" id="MyCache" scope="per-host"/>
 </sequence>
```

Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: You should have a Respond mediator in the `<onCacheHit></onCacheHit>`

Comment: Thanks Maria, But I didn't understand why respond mediator require which doesn't required here..... 
what I really need is Hash code value which is generated by DOMHASHGenerator class. I did make a try by extending this class but it couldn't help me out. 
Hash value like: :"1260-2-123901233395-6051-24-7996-128-8551"